# How to display all data in a table (and not showing the footer information)?

Tags: datatables

[image: Screenshot]

How do I hide that information automatically (and make sure everything is shown in one page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change following to display all record and hide that information

```
"sDom": 'r',
```

and

```
'iDisplayLength': -1,
```

and working example is here ...[example](http://jsfiddle.net/malde2025/9bvqG/32/)

Comment: Thanks, would you please let me know what is the `"sDom": '<"top">rt<"clear">',` for?

Comment: Yes, I am. I added those configurations but there is a `<div class="top"></div>` appeared which I don't need.

Comment: please use `"sDom": 'r'`